# AWS Transfer acceleration over FTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am aware of [AWS Transfer family](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-transfer-family/) of solutions.  The backing store for these is Amazon S3.  Then there is [AWS Transfer Acceleration](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/transfer-acceleration/) for S3.  Is it possible to leverage this acceleration capability while using AWS SFTP?

Comment: Are you experiencing poor data transfer speeds? Are you transferring data over large distances (eg between countries)? How are you measuring the current performance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein We have an upcoming use case where we plan to frequently be transferring large files.  So at this point it is a question driving out of curiosity.  Knowing what options exist would be useful.

Comment: Is there a particular need to get those large files transferred quickly? How many files are there, and how big are they? One option would be to use [AWS DataSync](https://aws.amazon.com/datasync/), but it would only be worthwhile for large quantities of data.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I wasn't aware of AWS DataSync; I'll have to keep that in mind.  Thanks.  As noted I _may not_ have an issue.  I am just staying prepared.  And yes, timeliness is a requirement.  And sFTP _may_ be the only option (I'll have to check into DataSync).  This is a case of transferring data from `A -> B` where `A` doesn't allow external access to pull and `B` doesn't allow external parties to push.  So Amazon's Transfer service is quite literally a transfer point.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/transfer-acceleration.html) cannot be used in front of the [AWS Transfer Family](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/what-is-aws-transfer-family.html).

However, [AWS Global Accelerator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/latest/dg/introduction-how-it-works.html) can apparently be used in front of the AWS Transfer Family endpoint for transfers over long haul networks that can leverage the AWS backbone can improve performance. This is especially beneficial for large files.

The difference is that S3 Transfer Acceleration can only point to S3, while Global Accelerator can direct any traffic that points to certain types of AWS resources, and it can even be configured to point to "local" resources based on geography.